# How to implement bus seat UI in swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to implement a simple bus seat UI in my ios app. I am using swiftui. I want to show two seats on left and two seats on right as in a real bus. The bus seat count will be dynamic, I will get it from API. So far I have not been able to get the desired UI.

```
import SwiftUI

struct BusSearchView: View {
    
    let seats: [Seat] = [Seat(id: 1, displayName: "1", isBooked: true),
                         Seat(id: 2, displayName: "2", isBooked: false),
                         Seat(id: 3, displayName: "3", isBooked: true),
                         Seat(id: 4, displayName: "4", isBooked: false),
                         Seat(id: 5, displayName: "5", isBooked: false),
                         Seat(id: 6, displayName: "6", isBooked: true),
                         Seat(id: 7, displayName: "7", isBooked: false),
                         Seat(id: 8, displayName: "8", isBooked: false),
                         Seat(id: 9, displayName: "9", isBooked: false),
    ]

        var body: some View {
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(), GridItem() , GridItem() , GridItem()]) {
                ForEach(seats) { seat in
                    Button(action: {
                        // Handle seat selection here
                        print(seat.displayName)
                    }) {
                        Text(seat.displayName)
                    }
                    .foregroundColor(seat.isBooked ? .gray : .black)
                }
            }
        }
}

struct Seat: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let displayName: String
    let isBooked: Bool
}
```

[image]

Comment: What info does the api provide about the seats? Most likely the layout of the seats will vary for different busses and not all rows might contain 4 seats.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it my own, and here is complete solution. It is not the best one and for scalability it still needs I think some type erasing and better abstraction, but for prototyping I think it is ok.

I've used a combination of SwiftUI's `ScrollView`, `HStack`, and `VStack` to create horizontally scrollable bus seat layout with vertical spacing between the upper and lower pairs of seats within each row.

```
import SwiftUI

struct BustView: View {
  // Mocking API data
  let seats: [Seat] = (0..<48).map { Seat(id: $0, displayName: String($0), isBooked: $0 % 2 == 0) }

  var body: some View {

    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
      HStack(spacing: 40) { // Spacing between each set of 4 seats (a row)
        ForEach(0..<seats.count / 4) { rowIndex in
          VStack { // Spacing for the aisle
            VStack(spacing: 10) { // Vertical spacing between pairs
              ForEach(0..<2) { upperLeftIndex in
                let index = rowIndex * 4 + upperLeftIndex
                if index < seats.count {
                  seatButton(for: seats[index])
                }
              }
            }
            Spacer().frame(height: 60)
            VStack(spacing: 10) { // Vertical spacing between pairs
              ForEach(2..<4) { lowerLeftIndex in
                let index = rowIndex * 4 + lowerLeftIndex
                if index < seats.count {
                  seatButton(for: seats[index])
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Helper function to render each seat button
  private func seatButton(for seat: Seat) -> some View {
    Button(action: {
      // Handle seat selection here
      print(seat.displayName)
    }) {
      Text(seat.displayName)
        .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
        .background(seat.isBooked ? Color.gray : Color.green)
        .foregroundColor(.white)
        .cornerRadius(8)
    }
  }
}

struct Seat: Identifiable {
  let id: Int
  let displayName: String
  let isBooked: Bool
}




struct ContentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    BustView()
      .padding()
  }
}
```

[image: Bussit-4-sit-per-row]